# A unique ID for a poll response

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my system a manager create a poll and publish it to the world so users which have the link to the poll can answer it.

There is some question which designed to receive multiple answers, so user can choose multiple distract in one response.

**The response table structure in the DB**

- ID
- ActivityID - the poll ID
- Value - the district value
- TimeResponse

In the database i am currently saving each response separately.

I will give you an example
Lets say there is 4 district in a poll (a,b,c,d)
User choose the following district (a,b,c)

The response table will look like this:

```
   ID       ActivityID      Value    TimeResponse
    1           234            a        01/01/2012 
    2           234            b        01/01/2012
    3           234            c        01/01/2012
```

So if i try to count the ID i will get the number 3 which represent the number of district were answered is a given poll.

BUT i need the number of responses per user in a given poll, so i need somehow to combine those two...

Until now i thought about the following solutions but neither of them is good.

- the first solution was to add a column of the user's IP, but sometimes i cant get the user's IP.
- the second solution was to add a column of the user's sessionID using the sessionIDManager, but if the user answer twice (2 response) it will store the same session ID.

FYI, the user which answer the poll is anonymous.

And also one of the system requirement is to allow a user to answer a poll several times

Comment: Can you combine the sessionID and the datetime, and assume all entries within a small (5 minute?) window constitute a single response?

Comment: I thought about it, but i can't assume that all entries will be within 5 minute window. i will like more accurate solution. i am considering this solution a compromise.

Comment: If a user can only answer once for each Activity, then you should add that constraint to your database, then in your code you will trap for a duplicate ActivityId and SessionId before you try to insert the record.

Comment: thank for your effort but the system require for user to answer several time in some cases

Comment: So what do you mean by _"but if the user answer twice (2 response) it will store the same session ID."_ - If you are allowing the user to answer multiple times for a particular Activity, can you explain in more detail what is _not_ good with your second solution that you mentioned?

Comment: users can answer a poll twice in one session. user get a unique session every time he open a new session of a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I can see.

One would be to generate a UUID every time the user answers the poll.  Create a column within the database, such as *AnswerID* and use this same UUID when you're creating the rows for each of their responses.  In C#, you can create a UUID with `Guid.NewGuid()`.  You could then count the number of responses by querying for the distinct *AnswerID* values.

The second approach would be to use a single row for each *set* of answers to a given question.  For example, if the user answered A, B and C, you'd store the response as "A/B/C".  This would make it harder to query for the total number of a certain answer, though some database systems might make this easier (for example, [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) has an indexable array type).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used the first solution, i have created a new Guid for each user response. thank you very much. it helped me a lot